# Java : utilization of @Deprecated with Cache Proxy Pattern

Tags: java, deprecated

I am in the process of creating a library for the teachers' timetable.

But I was wondering if I should put a class in @Deprecated or not.

Here is the case in which I am:

In the library, I have a `Schedule` class that collects the schedules from the school website.

And another `ScheduleProxy` class keeps in the cache the requests already made, thus avoiding the same request a second time.

### First solution with @Deprecated :

#### Schedule

```java
/**
 * 
 * @deprecated For the use of the Schedule class, it is preferable
 * to use its proxy: {@link ScheduleProxy} in order to have better response times.
 * 
 * @see InterfaceSchedule
 * @see ScheduleProxy
 */
@Deprecated(forRemoval = false)
public final class Schedule implements InterfaceSchedule {
/*
 * Code
 * 
 */
}
```

#### ScheduleProxy

```java
public final class ScheduleProxy implements InterfaceSchedule{
/*
 * Code
 * 
 */
}
```

### Second solution without @Deprecated :

#### Schedule

I changed the public to private package the `Schedule` class so the user doesn't use this class.

```java
/**
 * 
 * @see InterfaceSchedule
 * @see Schedule
 */
final class ConcreteSchedule implements InterfaceSchedule {
/*
 * Code
 * 
 */
}
```

#### ScheduleProxy

I changed the class name from "ScheduleProxy" to "Schedule" so that it would make it clearer to the library user.

```java
public final class Schedule implements InterfaceSchedule{
/*
 * Code
 * 
 */
}
```

### Question

So I wanted to ask you which of the two solutions is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution is more intuitive to the user and makes it impossible to use an API you actually don't want to be used. I'd say it's better.